# How to ask for remote permission in iOS 10/Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10

I want to ask the user for permissions (remote and local notifications, camera and audio) from a separate viewController.  The viewcontroller will be presented during the onboarding process, and never again.

How can I ask for permissions to display **remote notifications** outside the AppDelegate?
My question is not how to trigger them, but how to make sure that the AppDelegate is "responsible" for handling them once a permission have been granted.

**Current code in AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import PushKit
import CallKit


AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

let pushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    pushRegistry.delegate = self
    pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]


    ....

}
```

**ViewController where I ask for permission**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications


class AskForNotificationPermissionVC: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        requestPermissions { (videoGranted, audioGranted, notificationsGranted) in
            if videoGranted && audioGranted && notificationsGranted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPaySegue", sender: self)
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.presentSpecialPopoup()
                }
             }
        }
     }




    func requestPermissions (completion: @escaping ((Bool, Bool, Bool)->())) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate?

        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: { (videoGranted: Bool) -> Void in
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, completionHandler: { (audioGranted: Bool) -> Void in
                center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (notificationGranted:Bool, error) -> Void in
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    completion(videoGranted, audioGranted, notificationGranted)
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Any help is very, very much appreciated !!  Thank you.

Comment: Helpers seem to be confused. Please describe the issue more detailed. What is actually happening using your code? And what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
    //handle result
}
```

Comment: Someone edited the question which changed the meaning.  My question is not how to trigger the alert, but how to trigger the alert in a viewcontroller and at the same time do it so that the AppDelegate is able to handle the incoming Remote notifications.

Comment: You can call this method from anywhere, any viewController of your choice.

Comment: @FiReTiTi not a valid issue, KML is the original asker.